# React native + expo + Notifications = You must provide `notification.vapidPublicKey` in `app.json` to use push notifications on web

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I've been building an app on RN and static stuff are working as intended. Now I'm trying to add Push Notifications and all tries lead me to this error: `You must provide 'notification.vapidPublicKey' in 'app.json' to use push notifications on web.`.

There are several tutorials around and they all seems so simple and none of them have this error...

So, I've tried 5+ tutorials, using Node 14, react-native-web 0.11.7 (due async issues), including `owner`, `slug` and `notification.vapidPublicKey` on `app.json` (the last one is not accepted by the file), and a lot of other stuffs, like trying to have this working on a brand new project.

This error occours when I call `await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()` from `import { Notifications } from 'expo';`.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.1.0",
  "expo": "~37.0.3",
  "moment": "^2.27.0",
  "react": "~16.9.0",
  "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
  "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
  "react-native-web": "0.11.7"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
  "@types/react": "~16.9.23",
  "@types/react-native": "~0.61.17",
  "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
  "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
  "typescript": "~3.8.3"
},
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Comment: As far as I know current EXPO 38 is not supporting push notifications for web. There were some parts of the API where web worked it is not supported. See https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/8853/

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to react native and it seems that we have to develop with a mobile device (or emulate one) and not with the browser.

Comment: Seems a little ridiculous that they can't just give a "web notifications not supported" warning instead of throwing a cryptic error with a broken documentation link...

Comment: That's true. Even if we try to search on Expo website about this, nothing shows up...

Comment: And the link that comes with the error gives a 404 ```You must provide `notification.vapidPublicKey` in `app.json` to use push notifications on web. Learn more: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-vapid/``` if they said that they don't support it anymore, would have save hours